# my code doesnt work ! Java- beginners

Tags: java

```
public Tier() {

    anzahldertiere++;           

    int sumderzahlen = 5 + 1;
    System.out.println("5 + 1 = " + sumderzahlen);          

    int diffderzahlen = 10 - 2;
    System.out.println("10 - 2 = " - diffderzahlen);        

    int multderzahlen = 3 * 3;
    System.out.println("3 * 3 = " * multderzahlen);          

    int divderzahlen = 27 / 3;
    System.out.println("27 / 3 = " / divderzahlen);         

    int modderzahlen = 10 % 1;
    System.out.println("10 % 3 = " % modderzahlen);
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Tier dasTier = new Tier();
 }
```

**QUestion**, why does the first additi work when i run the program but the other dont for example de 10-2 one wont work. just the first one.

any ideas ?

Comment: you can set a good title for your question

Comment: I'd definitely encourage you to include more details beyond "didn't work" (e.g. The text of the error message) to make this easier to find if someone else has a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When printing, you use only + sign and after that a variable (or method) comes that you want to print a value from. So you would change all the negative or multiplications signs to + sign. From next time, just use + signs

```
anzahldertiere++;           

int sumderzahlen = 5 + 1;
System.out.println("5 + 1 = " + sumderzahlen);          

int diffderzahlen = 10 - 2;
System.out.println("10 - 2 = " + diffderzahlen);        

int multderzahlen = 3 * 3;
System.out.println("3 * 3 = " + multderzahlen);          

int divderzahlen = 27 / 3;
System.out.println("27 / 3 = " + divderzahlen);         

int modderzahlen = 10 % 1;
System.out.println("10 % 3 = " + modderzahlen);
```

Comment: @YCF_L yes sorry i changed it

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like `"10 % 3 = " % modderzahlen` doesn't really make sense. To begin with, you're not actually doing the operation there, you're just appending strings.

To illustrate why Java doesn't allow this, consider what would happen if I did `"someRandomString" % 10`. What should the outcome of this operation be? Thus, Java (correctly) recognizes that it doesn't make sense to do operations like `*`, `/`, or `%` on strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("5 + 1 = " + sumderzahlen);
```

In the code above you have the + to append, basically you are saying compiler, write what is between " " and after it put the value sumderzahlen.

try this:

```
int sumderzahlen = 5 + 1;
System.out.println("5 + 1 = " + sumderzahlen);

int diffderzahlen = 10 - 2;
System.out.println("10 - 2 = " + diffderzahlen);        

int multderzahlen = 3 * 3;
System.out.println("3 * 3 = " + multderzahlen);          

int divderzahlen = 27 / 3;
System.out.println("27 / 3 = " + divderzahlen);         

int modderzahlen = 10 % 1;
System.out.println("10 % 3 = " + modderzahlen);
```